# How many tallies does Toko Fukawa have on her leg exactly?

Tags: danganronpa

[image: tally 1]

[image: tally 2]

Here's 2 pictures I have of her showing her tallies!

Comment: Assuming the tally's on her legs shown has the same representation as the general english tally (being `卌 = 5`) and that each strike is a 1 the bottom image, which shows more, shows 62. however as i said this assumes that the markings on her legs compare to 1 strike = 1 and the completed mark = 5 and this is only going by what's visable, can not discount that her skirt is hiding the rest

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: there's *no exact* number, the tally marks changed from one to other titles.

For reference, this is how the Japanese tally marks work for 1 to 5:

> [image: Japanese tally marks]

Ignoring the fan arts since there are too many variants,

1. **Danganronpa: Trigger Happy Havoc**

   [image: DR1]

   Probably 32. It seems she wrote the mark from top-to-bottom (from her POV), thus finishing the first row of 20 (4x5). Continuing to the bottom row, there are 3 visible characters. Assuming she wrote it from left-to-right, the first 2 characters should have finished, making them 10 (2x5). The last character seems to stop at 2.
2. **Danganronpa: The Animation** (correspond to *DR: Trigger Happy Havoc*)

   [image: DR:Anime]

   At least 30. The visible tally marks are in form of 2 rows of 3 characters, and all of them are complete, making them 30 (2x3x5).
3. **Danganronpa Another Episode: Ultra Despair Girls**

   [image: DR:AE 3D model]

   The 3D model only shows 4 characters and in the same pattern with *DR1* with the last character stops at 2. Since the rest are probably hidden by her skirt, at least 17 (+ multiple of 5), or possibly 32 (same as *DR1*).

   [image: DR:AE in-game artwork]

   However, her in-game artwork shows different tally marks. There area 3 rows of 3 characters instead. The bottom-middle character seems to be the last character and stops at 2. It's probably 37 (7x5 + 2).
4. **Cyber Danganronpa VR: The Class Trial** (correspond to *DR: Trigger Happy Havoc*)

   (Caution: probably NSFW, panty image)

   > [image: DR:VR]

   Probably 27 or 37. The visible tally marks are in form of 2 rows of 3 characters, while the last character stops at 2. There might be another pair hidden behind her thigh, making the total to 37.
5. **Divine Gate** (collaboration)

   [image: DG]

   Probably 37. The visible tally marks are in form of 2 rows of 4 characters (the first pair is hidden in the shadow), and the last character stops at 2.

**Conclusion**

The tally marks are between 17-37, with 32 & 37 as possible answers. However, one certain thing is, *the last character stops at 2*.